# ADSI will not connect to IIS from XP Workstation

Tags: iis, adsi

I'm successfully using VBScript within WScript to remotely read and write IIS configurations from the server. When I attempt to run these same scripts from my desk box they fail, though. Example:

```
Dim vdir
Set vdir = GetObject("IIS://servername/w3svc/226/root")
```

Error = "Invalid syntax"

The code works perfectly when run from one IIS server to another, but I'd like to run it from my XP Workstation. It would seem reasonable that there's a download of ADSI available that will make things work from my desktop, but I cannot find one. I downloaded [ADAM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9688F8B9-1034-4EF6-A3E5-2A2A57B5C8E4&displaylang=en) but that only got me a small portion of the functionality I need.

Any hints out there? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephbu is correct and that answer was helpful, but it is not sufficient. In order to use ADSI remotely from my XP workstation, I needed to install IIS 5.1. Once that was installed, all my scripts started working. If there is an installation that can make the scripts work without making my computer an IIS server, I am unaware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the IIS ADSI Provider isn't installed/registered  (probable cause of the syntax error on the protocol IIS: in the string)

Just tracking down where the provider DLLs come from - suspect it gets installed with:

[IIS 6.0 Management Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=F9C1FB79-C903-4842-9F6C-9DB93643FDB7&displaylang=en)